# Fixed Header and Footer not allowing page content to scroll?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently working on making my header and my footer fixed while my page content scrolls through. My body has overflow: hidden; currently. When I remove it I can scroll through the page, however, my header is no longer fixed at the top and my footer still covers the last bit of my page content. I'm pulling the content through php. How can I keep my header and footer fixed on the page, but still allow my PHP dynamic content appear completely?

My code:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 40px 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
}

#page {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<head id="header">
    <?php
    include('incl/menuinc.php');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            switch ($_GET['page']) {
                case 'example_page':
                    include('incl/pages/example.php');
                    break;
                default:
                    include('home.php');
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <?php
        include('footer.php')
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: can you use Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: I don't know Javascript or Jquery, but if you have a solution I could look up, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/q8j208eo/2/

```
*{ /*basic reset*/
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html, body{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#header{
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

#footer{
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

#page{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: The page content helped a lot, thanks!! How would I make my header stick? It still doesn't.

Comment: This helped! Thank you so much!